# How to move all files of folder from another folder to same S3 bucket in script elixir

Tags: amazon-s3, elixir, bucket

I'm making a script that needs to move all files from a third folder to the main one and in that list there are also those that are already in the right folder and I need to ignore them.

LIKE THIS: **my_bucket/files/id/file.txt** TO **my_bucket/files/file.txt**

my code is like this and it is only listing the objects, it is not moving

I try this code:

```
defmodule Script.Elixir do
 
  
  def list_objects_in_bucket do
    "my_bucket"
    |> ExAws.S3.list_objects(max_keys: 1000)
    |> ExAws.request()
    |> extract_only_route()
  end

  def copy_object(origin_path) do
    ExAws.S3.put_object_copy(
      "my_bucket/",
      "/my_folder_destiny/",
      "my_bucket",
      origin_path
    )
    |> ExAws.request()
  end

  defp extract_only_route({:ok, %{body: %{contents: contents}}}) do
    Enum.map(contents, fn %{key: route} -> route end)
  end

end
```

Comment: Please share what `list_objects_in_bucket/0` returns (a minified example.)

Comment: returns a list like this:
[files/id/87887.txt, files/id/23873.txt, ....] @AlekseiMatiushkin

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a list of files with `list_objects_in_bucket/0`, and a tested `copy_object/2` function, accepting arguments `from` and `to`, you might do somewhat like

```elixir
@bucket "my_bucket/"
@top "files/"
@nested "id/"

# https://hexdocs.pm/ex_aws_s3/ExAws.S3.html#put_object_copy/5
copy_object = fn from, to ->
  @bucket
  |> ExAws.S3.put_object_copy(to, @bucket, from)
  |> ExAws.request()
end

for @bucket <> @top <> @nested <> name <- list_objects_in_bucket() do
  copy_object.(@top <> @nested <> name, @top <> name)
end
```

Comment: this function ```copy_object``` not working, is function the move or copy the files @Aleksei

Comment: I have amended the answer with to most likely working code for `copy_object/2`.